# Proving these norms are not equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$X$ is the vector space containting all polynomials with real coefficients. For every $P \in X$, define $N_1(P)= \sup _ {t \in [0,1]} |P(t)|$ and $N(P)=N_1(P)+|P'(1)|$. Prove that $N$ is not equivalent to $N_1$.

$P'$ is the derivative of $P$.

So they are equivalent if there exists $a,b>0$ such that $aN \leq N_1 \leq bN$ or $aN_1 \leq N \leq bN_1$ but I cant find such a polynomial that would break any of these conditions...

Comment: I think you mean $N_1(P)=\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |P(t)|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if two norms are equivalent they induce the same notion of convergence.

In the first norm $P_n(t):=1/n\ t^n$ converges to zero, as $N_1(P_n) =1/n$. In the second norm however $N(P_n)=1/n+1$ and $P_n$ doesn't converge to zero.

Comment: i dont get how the n came in. We had to prove that N_1 and N were norms and i used P(t) all that time... So what function of t did you choose? P(t)=(1/n)t^n? where n is very large?

Comment: its says X is the vs containing all polynomials, so how can you choose the polynomial to be a sequence like u did?

Comment: I had switched the argument of the polynomial from $t$ to $x$ without noticing it. To be more specific, $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of polynomials in $X$, where $P_n(t)=1/n \ t^n$. With respect to the norm given by $N_1$, you have $N_1(P_n(t))=1/n$ (the polynomial being maximal at $t=1$). Notice that $\partial_t P_n(t)=t^{n-1}$, so $\partial_t P_n(1)=1$ if $n>0$. This means $N(P_n)=1/n +1$.